Failing to find elements by xpath with selenium Java
I'm opening https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/earnings with Java selenium webdriver and trying to query the table row elements that have the HTML like
<div part="table-row" "="" role="row" class="table-row " data-row-index="6">

with my code
List<WebElement> rows = driver.findElements(
          By.xpath("//div[@part='table-row']"));

But I get an empty list. Also tried
List<WebElement> rows = driver.findElements(
          By.xpath("//div[@class='table-row']"));

with the same result.
(notice there is a trailing space in the classname in the HTML but selenium doesn't allow adding a trailing space).
Any help is much appreciated.

The table you are trying to access is inside of a shadow element. You have to get the shadow root element and get the SearchContext of the shadow root from there. Then using the search context you'll be able to find the table elements.
FYI The following code is for selenium 4. There are other methods to get the shadow root.
Try the following,
    driver.get("https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/earnings");
    SearchContext shadowRoot = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div > nsdq-table-sort")).getShadowRoot();
    List<WebElement> rows = shadowRoot.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.table-row"));

